# Writing SELECT query to loop all the items in a list of items

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, loops, select

I have situation where I need to write a sql select query which is technically need to be repeated to all the items in a list.

For example, say I have list like this,

```
list =[ { item_1: value_11,
          item_2: value_12,
          item_3: value_13,
          item_4: value_14'
        },
        { item_1: value_21,
          item_2: value_22,
          item_3: value_23,
          item_4: value_24,
        },
        { item_1: value_31,
          item_2: value_32,
          item_3: value_33,
          item_4: value_34,
        },
        ......
      ];
```

Now I need to write a SELECT query to get all the related records for each of the item, something like,

```
//for each item
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tbl.fld1 = list[0].item_1 AND tbl.fld2 = list[0].item_2 AND tbl.fld3 = list[0].item_3 AND tbl.fld4 = list[0].item_4;
```

Is it possible to write a single query for the same within SQL statement (kind of loop) or else does it need to be repeated from the coding side so it will call the db for each items separately.

Please help,

Thank You in advance

Comment: since you have to pass the data somehow to the query, there is no other way than to loop over your list.

Comment: (...unless the data is already on the database of course. then you could use a `join`. )

Answer (score 0):

As @draz already commented you need to loop over the list to dynamically create the sql statement. You can loop over it in your code and generate a single sql statement that can be send to the database once.

A simple but probably not the nicest idea would be something like:

```
sql_select = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE";
first_item = true;
for (element in list) {
    sql_select = (first_item) ? sql_select : sql_select + " OR";
    fist_item = false;
    where_clause = ` (tbl.fld1 = ${element.item_1} AND tbl.fld2 = ${element.item_2} AND tbl.fld3 = ${element.item_3} AND tbl.fld4 = ${element.item_4})`;
    sql_select.concat(where_clause); 
}
```

Comment: I think this'd be fine when the list is small but not when it is too large.. anyway thank you for your reply